# Rscript vs. source: What are the key differences?

Tags: r

This might be a very basic question, but have not found a convincing answer yet. When executing an R script within the R environment, I can either do `source(foo.R)` or `system("Rscript foo.R")`. Is there any difference at all between the two approaches, and if so how do the two approaches compare?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

They're fundamentally different in their effects.

- `source("foo.R")` tells your **current** R process to take its input from `"foo.R"`.
- `system("Rscript foo.R")` uses an operating system command to launch a **separate** R process, within which the contents of `"foo.R"` are evaluated.

The `Rscript` call won't directly affect your current R session at all, *except* that it will by default print the output of that other R session on your current console. (You can disable this in your `system()` call by setting `show.output.on.console=FALSE`).

Answer (score 3):

I think `source(foo.R)` includes the source code of that file (`foo.R`) into your current environment. If you define a variable within `foo.R`, let's say `x <- 5`, and in your current project you define `x <- 6` beforehand, `x` becomes `5`.

`system("Rscript foo.R")` runs the `Rscript` program with the argument `foo.R`, so your current environment is not affected at all.

Comment: would it achieve the same results as `sys.source`? i understand that using `Rscript` would be most useful when executing an independent set of scripts.

Comment: `sys.source()` is a close cousin of `source()` --- the `source` help page calls `sys.source` a "streamlined version".  It looks likely to me that `sys.source` was mainly designed for its use by `library()`.

Answer (score 2):

As an answer to @Ramnath's comment: `sys.source("foo")` is not the same as `Rscript foo`. For example, you can do the following with `sys.source`:

```
e <- new.env()
sys.source("foo", e)  # foo creates a bunch of objects in environment e
z <- with(e, {
    # do stuff with e....
})
rm(e)
```

You might do this if you are creating several intermediate objects, which you then do stuff on and return a final result. You don't want to keep the intermediate objects, so putting them into their own temporary environment is an easy way to remove them in one go.